# CSVReader Align Columns

Tags: tables, csvsimple

Is there a way to right justify the second field (after the `\dotfill`)?

I tried using flushright, but that did not do what I was hoping for.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\begin{filecontents*}{Annex01}
Acceleration, Non-plotted,{C12.24}
Acceleration, Unplotted,{C12.24}
Active Terminal Guidance,{FD5.2, XFD5.2}
Administrative Shuttles,{J2.0, XJ2.0, YJ2.0}
Warp-Field Distortion Mine Versus ESGs,{M93.36}
Warp-Field Distortion Mine Versus Status Fields,{M93.34}
Warp-Field Distortion Mine Versus Temporal Elevator,{M93.37}
\end{filecontents*}

\csvreader[no head]{Annex01}{1=\name,2=\whereis}{\noindent\name\dotfill\whereis\par}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. To highlight code-blocks, either indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui.

Comment: Could you please add a sketch of the desired output?

Comment: I am not sure what is meant by In thus variable OUT.  As I understand the filecontents command anything in a set of brackets is a field.  There should only be two fields.


The result I am trying to achieve is:

Acceleration, Non-plotted …….. C12.24

Administrative Shuttles …...…… J2.0, XJ2.0, 
                                                     YJ2.0

Warp-Field Distortion Mine Versus 
Temporal Elevator …………….. M93.37

I was able to get close using a access report but this is only one report of many that I am trying to put into a single document.